# Is there a way to generate a swagger specification file from C++ code?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I've a requirement to create a HTTP API layer over a legacy API interface written in C++. My plan is to generate the Swagger or open API file and then make it available to bunch of projects that needs to write a client (who will be consumer of new API) or a server (wrapper to legacy API).

Is there anything that can expedite this requirement (other than manually parsing them and creating swagger spec file)?
i.e. using C++ code to generate swagger JSON/YML file

Comment: You may take a look at https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-swagger. It provides annotation - like swagger-ui generation. But it requires oatpp as your server framework

Answer (score 2):

Quite late answer and I think that with no good news.

If you're talking about the implementation of Annotations in C++. As far as I know the [Swagger Core Annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#swagger-core-annotations) are part of the [Swagger Core Project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core), and in the documentation you can find:

> Swagger Core **is a Java implementation of the OpenAPI Specification**.
>   Current version supports JAX-RS2.

Also the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core#prerequisites) says:

> You need the following installed and available in your `$PATH`:
>
> - Java 8
> - Apache maven 3.0.4 or greater
> - Jackson 2.4.5 or greater

Answer (score -3):

you've been tried [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/) is an API that serves for a bunch of languages inclusive **C++**

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite, swagger spec from code. Like Swagger2Feature serves swagger spec from JAX-RS service endpoints, I want the dynamic swagger definition created from the C++ code. Why? No manual swagger creation for a large number of endpoints. Also, any additions to service entry point will get the latest swagger. Here what I managed: Parsed the service endpoint definitions in the C++ code(used pycparser) got the specifics of service endpoint/operation and then generated the swagger from it.