# Annotating C++ code for generating swagger json/yaml

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I know that there is a way to generate the client-side code from the swagger yaml with swagger-codegen, but is there a way to generate the swagger yaml with the C++ annotations similar to what can be done in Java.

There seem to be annotation libraries available for other languages e.g python C# (https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/swagger-annotation-libraries/) but I am not able to find any support for C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to generate a Swagger specification file from C/C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53699268/113116)

Comment: @Helen I saw the post and there was no answer in that post. That is why I created this post.

Answer (score 1):

I don`t think so. As far as I know the [Swagger Core Annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#swagger-core-annotations) are part of the [Swagger Core Project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core), and in the documentation you can find:

> Swagger Core **is a Java implementation of the OpenAPI Specification**.
>   Current version supports JAX-RS2.

Also the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core#prerequisites) says:

> You need the following installed and available in your `$PATH`:
>
> - Java 8
> - Apache maven 3.0.4 or greater
> - Jackson 2.4.5 or greater

***Update:***

I'm not quite sure if [oatpp-swagger](https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp-swagger) can fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks it seems that there are annotation libraries available for languages other than Java (https://swagger.io/blog/api-development/swagger-annotation-libraries/) But I could find anything on C++.

Comment: oatpp-swagger provides annotation - like swagger-ui generation. But it requires oatpp as your rest framework